# ASP.NET mvc Ajax Helper DropDownListFor send selected item value as parameter to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, dropdownlistfor, ajaxhelper

**Problem**
I want my Ajax form to pass the value of the selected DropDownListFor to the controller but I can't figure out why the controller is not taking any value.
I am working with ASP.NET MVC and I would like to stick with the helper functions as much as I can.

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions {
HttpMethod = "Get", 
UpdateTargetId = "UserResults",
InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Roles, new SelectLi(ViewBag.Groups 
    as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "Text"), "Select a group",
    new { id = "Value", onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
}
@Html.Partial("_UsersGroup", ViewData)
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult test(int? selectGroup)
{

// Generate dropdownlist Groups
List<SelectListItem> groupList = new List<SelectListItem>();
var query = from s in db.Roles select s;
if (query.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var v in query)
    {
        groupList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = v.Name, Value =
        v.ID.ToString() });
    }
}
ViewBag.Groups = groupList;
// End

// This part is supposed to take the passed value as parameter
if (selectGroup == null)
{
    // To do code comes here, which takes selectGroup as parameter
}
```

**Details**

The form should pass a value based on the selection to the controller which takes it as "selectGroup".

*ps. this is my first time asking a question, I'm sorry if I made mistakes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of you method needs to match the name of the control which is `name="Roles"` so the method should be

```
public ActionResult test(int? roles)
```

Other potential issues with your code

Your controller generates `List<SelectListItem>` for use by the dropdownlist. There is no need for the unnecessary extra overhead of then creating a new `SelectList` (which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) from it. The view code can simply be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Roles, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Groups, "Select a group")`

Do not use `Model` (capital M) in the expression. If you make any other reference to the model in your view (e.g. `@Model.SomeProperty`) you will get an error. Using lower case `model => model.somProperty` is OK but you can simply use `m => m.someProperty`

The helper will generate an `id` attribute (in you case `id="Role"`) so it seems unclear why you are adding `new { id = "Value", ..}`, especially since you don't appear to be referencing the element by its `id` anywhere

Learn to use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting you mark up with behavior. Remove the `onclick` attribute and use `$('#Roles').change(function() { $('form').submit(); });`

Comment: Thank you very much! Definitely going to learn Unobstrusive JavaScript. I'm just very new to programming. I just recently learned how to work with mvc asp.net aswell.